# Run docker-compose with remote debug. Intelij, Java 11

Tags: java, spring, docker, intellij-idea, docker-compose

I applied the steps from the guide to my project(https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/run-and-debug-a-spring-boot-application-using-docker-compose.html).
Summarizing, I added this line to Dockerfile `-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom` and command to docker-compose `command: java -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom -jar /usr/app/test-app.jar`.
After clicking on the debug button near command at docker-compose, the remote configuration is:

```
Debugger mode: Attach to remote JVM
Transport: Socket
Host: localhost
Port: 5005
Command line arguments for remote JVM: -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=*:5005;
```

Docker Compose run configuration(Before launch) options:

```
--------------------------------------------------
Port               | Local port | Container port |
-------------------------------------------------|
Java Debugger port | 5005       | 5005           |
--------------------------------------------------

Custom command: java -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=5005 -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom -jar /usr/app/test-app.jar
Custom options: -p 5005:5005
```

Running the configuration I received exception :
`Error running 'Remote JVM Debug with compose': Unable to open debugger port (localhost:5005): java.net.ConnectException "Connection refused: connect"`

I tried to fix this by changing address to `*:<port>`. **The resulting custom command is**
`java -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=*:5005 -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom -jar /usr/app/test-app.jar`.
Then I get exception:
`Error running 'Remote JVM Debug with compose': Unable to open debugger port (localhost:5005): java.io.IOException "handshake failed - connection prematurally closed"`.
Also I tried to change the port to 8080, but the result is the same. How to fix this problem and have remote configuration with docker-compose(Before launch)?
Project to demonstrate the problem: https://github.com/leonaugust/intelij_docker_problem

**Dockerfile**

```
# Build stage
FROM maven:3.6.0-jdk-11-slim AS build
COPY src /usr/src/app/src
COPY pom.xml /usr/src/app
RUN mvn -f /usr/src/app/pom.xml clean package -DskipTests

# Run stage
FROM adoptopenjdk/openjdk11:alpine-jre
COPY --from=build /usr/src/app/target/test-app.jar /usr/app/test-app.jar
EXPOSE 8080
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar", "-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom","/usr/app/test-app.jar"]
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3.1'
services:

  test-app:
    build: .
    container_name: test-app
    image: test-app

    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    command: java -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom -jar /usr/app/test-app.jar
```

Comment: Does not work for me either. Seems like a bug in IntelliJ as setting custom command does not replace the entrypoint in container at all. You could add  `entrypoint: java -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=*:5005 -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom -jar /usr/app/test-app.jar` in your `docker-compose` file and try.

Comment: `ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar", "-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom","/usr/app/test-app.jar"]` are you sure it is a correct order of arguments? In a **Dockerfile** Try ``ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom", "-jar","/usr/app/test-app.jar"]``

Answer (score 0):

In a `Dockerfile` try:

`ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom", "-jar","/usr/app/test-app.jar"]`

Comment: Produces the same result.  `handshake failed - connection prematurally closed`
Although, it's important to notice that @michalk suggestion to add entrypoint
to docker-compose file works. `entrypoint: java agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=*:5005 -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom -jar /usr/app/test-app.jar`

Answer (score 0):

Change the keyword `ENTRYPOINT` in `Dockerfile` to `CMD`.